# .expect assertions not working when moved to a function in page model

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

Replacing .wait(8000) with logic to check whether page inside iframe has loaded before we click to move on.  When the code is in the tests, it works fine.  I've attempted to move the code into a function in the page model and the clicks are premature (ie same as if the .wait() value was set too low).

I've tried separating the checks into 2 different functions with the same results.

in test

```
         .expect(navigation.appRowFadeIn.exists).ok({ timeout: 8000 });
    await t
         .switchToIframe(navigation.iframe)
         .expect(navigation.pageFrame.exists).ok({ timeout: 10000 });
    await t
         .switchToMainWindow()
```

in page model

```
export class Navigation {

    constructor(
        public appRowFadeIn: Selector = Selector('.apps-row.fade-in'),
        public iframe: Selector = Selector('#app-runner'),
        public pageFrame: Selector = Selector('#page_frame')        

    ) { }

    async appnavigation() {
        await t
            .expect(Selector(this.appRowFadeIn).exists).ok({ timeout: 8000 });
        await t
            .switchToIframe(this.iframe)
            .expect(Selector(this.pageFrame).exists).ok({ timeout: 9000 });
        await t
            .switchToMainWindow()
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the `appnavigation` should be :

```
async appnavigation() {
  await t
   .expect(this.appRowFadeIn.exists).ok({ timeout: 8000 });
  await t
   .switchToIframe(this.iframe)
   .expect(this.pageFrame.exists).ok({ timeout: 9000 });
  await t
   .switchToMainWindow()
}
```

Comment: Corrected but result is the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

needed an 'await' when calling function in the test.  Test wasn't waiting for function to complete before moving on.

```
await navigation.appnavigation();
```

Thanks.